# Get list of ids - Odoo

Tags: odoo-9

I want get a list of ids in odoo 9...

No working because expected a singleton

```
order_recs = order_obj.search([('date_order','<=',previous_start_date),('date_order','>=',previous_new_rec_date)]).id

order_line_recs = order_line_obj.search([('order_id','in',order_recs)])
```

I expected order_line_recs with a list o order_line

Comment: Can you provide more information or reference code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the `id` attribute, you should use ids. Example:

```
order_recs = order_obj.search([('date_order','<=',previous_start_date),('date_order','>=',previous_new_rec_date)]).ids
```

Which will return the list of ids from the RecordSet.